# Горячие клавиши для программы

Tags: delphi, hotkeys

Я сделал маленькую полезную программу; мне надо, чтоб были в ней горячие клавиши, то есть я поставил Button1, чтоб при нажатии на нее программа выводила сообщение. Но я хочу, чтоб когда она была в трее и я нажимал, к примеру, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, то это сообщение выводилось.

Comment: RegisterHotKey же!

Answer (score 1):

[@karmadro4](/users/6679/karmadro4) вам уже подсказал WinApi-функцию для реализации, я же лишь уточню:

```
RegisterHotKey(handle, 0, MOD_CONTROL, ord('A'));
```

Comment: Рано уточнять, пусть человек сначала ман прочитает. Копипаста-то всё равно не заработает.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что `handle` - это идентификатор приложения?

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, здесь - идентификатор окна.

Comment: @karmadro4? это не копипаста, представьте!

Comment: @CostantinoRupert `handle` - это хэндл окна (`HWND`) в которое будет отправлено оконное сообщение о нажатии горячей клавиши. В вашем случае это, скорее всего, будет хэндл главной формы.